How can I programmatically scroll horizontally without scrolling vertically?
I am trying to build a simple, progressively enhancing image slider.
The basis works fully without JavaScript: using link anchors, flexbox, and scroll-snap-align, the behaviour is already quite nice and functionally complete.
As a progressive enhancement, I want to get rid of the vertical scrolling that happens upon clicking the anchor links.
The obvious attempt is to preventDefault() when the hash in the URL changes (i.e., when the links are clicked) and do the scrollTo() in JavaScript with the top option set to the current scroll position.
Here my current code:


function horizontal_anchor() {
  var hash = decodeURIComponent(location.hash); // decode special chars like spaces
  var element = document.getElementById(hash.substring(1));
  if (element) {
    var parent = element.closest(".slide");
    let targetTop =
      window.pageYOffset !== undefined
        ? window.pageYOffset
        : (
            document.documentElement ||
            document.body.parentNode ||
            document.body
          ).scrollTop;
    parent.scrollTo({
      left: element.offsetLeft,
      top: targetTop,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
    console.log(
      "Scrolled to " +
        element.offsetLeft +
        ", top " +
        targetTop +
        "."
    );
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // on load
  if (location.hash) horizontal_anchor();
  // on URL change
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    horizontal_anchor();
    return false;
  });
});
/**
* CSS of the slider
*/
.slider {
  max-width: 30em;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: fit-content;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;

  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  z-index: 8;
  margin: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 1em;
}

.nav-next {
  right: 0;
}

.nav-prev {
  left: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

/** CSS of the rest */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.long-content {
  background: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%,
    rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%
  );
  padding-top: 50em;
}
<div class="parallax-wrapper">
  <div class="long-content"></div>

  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="image-slider slider">
      <div class="slide" id="prev">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1726711340699-952d47133b21?w=900&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxmZWF0dXJlZC1waG90b3MtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHx8" />
        <a href="#next" class="slider-nav nav-next">Next</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="next">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1725714834984-4f37a2406563?w=900&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxmZWF0dXJlZC1waG90b3MtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHx8" />
        <a href="#prev" class="slider-nav nav-prev">Prev</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="long-content"></div>
</div>



In this example, when you click on Next or Prev, respectively, the page is scrolled such that the image ends up at the top of the window (iframe), rather than keeping it where it is, vertically.
Additionally, the behaviour: "smooth" does not seem to be respected.

"The obvious attempt is to preventDefault() when the hash in the URL changes" - when you comment out the call to horizontal_anchor in that handler function, you'll see that the page still jumps so that the image aligns on top of the viewport - so apparently your attempt to prevent the event default there didn't work to begin with.

Hm, thanks @C3roe, I guess that also explains why the scroll behaviour is not smooth. Remains the question, why, and how I can prevent the default instead? I guess for the latter I can investigate simply overriding the click event, but no clue on how to investigate the former

You will probably have to prevent the default of the link click action, and then invoke your horizontal_anchor function from there. If you still need the URL hash to change, then use the History API to do so.

Please click [edit], then [<>] and post a [mcve] HERE so we do not need to go to a possibly changed or deleted external link

It appears that while the hashchange is fired, it is fired too late. The navigation by the browser due to the link happens first, leading to the vertical scrolling without any behavior: "smooth".
To solve this, one can add the event handler to the link instead:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document.body.classList.add("js-ready");
  // on load
  if (location.hash) horizontal_anchor();
  // on URL change
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    horizontal_anchor();
    return false;
  });

  // on click
  document.querySelectorAll(".slider-nav").forEach(function (a) {
    a.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      history.pushState(null, null, a.getAttribute("href"));
      horizontal_anchor();
    });
  });
});


